# Transitioning anchor side

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a container, which contains some things including a box at the bottom. I have a need to transition that box from the bottom to the top.

```
from {
    bottom: 4px;
    top: auto;
}
to {
    bottom: auto;
    top: 4px;
}
```

For obvious reasons, this doesn't work. You can't transition/animate with an `auto` value. I've worked around this by having the box fade out and slide off the bottom, then fade in and slide on the top. This works, but it feels longer than it needs to be.

The box has dynamic height, and the entire thing is responsive so pre-calculated values are right out.

Any ideas? Or is what I have now the best I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's definitely possible, but instead of trying to achieve it with a combination of `top` and `bottom`, you can achieve it with using `top` and `translate`. This will allow you to have a clear point for your **stop** and **start** whilst still giving you the freedom of a responsive container.

It would look something like this:

```
from {
    top: 4px;
    transform: translateY(0);
}

to {
    top: calc(100% - 4px);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

Here's an example in action, (*I've used a `textarea` so that you can resize and keep testing, the button(+js) is just there to help facilitate the class change*)

```js
$('.go').click(function(){
    $('textarea').toggleClass('up');
});
```

```css
textarea {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
  transition: all 1s ease 0s;
  left: 150px;
}

textarea.up {
  top: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="go">
TRANSITION
</button>
<textarea></textarea>
```

And a [Fiddle if you prefer that instead](https://jsfiddle.net/bofnch2n/).

Comment: Outstanding. I've adjusted it slightly to avoid the need for `calc`, by using `translateY(100%) translateY(4px)` to keep the "padding" in there, and it works flawlessly. Thank you very much.

Comment: Awesome :) I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate the `top` property by using the `calc()` CSS function :

```
from {
    bottom: 4px;
}
to {
    bottom: calc(100% - 4px - yourContainerHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use animations to do this. You don't have to change bottom to top. Just use one of them. I chose to use 'bottom' . Then to simulate the `top:4px` you move the box with `bottom:calc(100% - 4px)` and together with `transform:translateY(100%)` . This is equal to `top:4px` .

see snippet below

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  animation-name: fromBottom;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-duration: 0.8s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  transform: translateY(0%)
}

@keyframes fromBottom {
  0% {
    bottom: 0;
    transform: translateY(0%)
  }
  100% {
    bottom: calc(100% - 4px);
    transform: translateY(100%)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">

  </div>
</div>
```